# Click out from the division to let it close

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, show

```js
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.featured-menu3').hide(0);
    $('.navul li#fnav3').click(function() {

      if($(this).children(".featured-menu3").is(':visible')){

        $('.featured-menu3').hide();
      }

      else {

        $(".featured-menu3").show();
      }

    });

  });

</script>
```

I tried when I clicked out from the divison, the tab doesnt close. It will only close when I click the division only. Any other input?

Thank You

Comment: You should use .not method of jquery for this.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm quite lost, cause for now I'm stuck and dont know any other way.

Comment: I will get you help. Can you create a jsfiddle or plunker for this problem ?